# Is there any method to find timestamp of old records in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Earlier there was no **TIMESTAMP** column in my **TABLE**.

Is there any method by which i can get Record Entry time like **TIMESTAMP** in mysql.

If any! Plz suggest.

Comment: Oof that bold text. You dont have to actually accent your text, like its important for keywords. We can read it just fine. And if you dont have it stored via a binary log on your server, no, no way to retrieve timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled [binay log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html) you can retrive all transaction time Otherwise it is impossible. Bad news is the binary log    is disabled by default.

Comment: Yeah my binary logs are disabled to save space.My bad luck.Thanks.